# Why does this arrow function not the same as the non-arrow function with the same signature?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

I have two functions with the same signature(supposedly), but it seems they are not the same from the compiler's view: the `todos` in the arrow function is of `Todo[]` type, while the `todos` in the NON-arrow function is of `any` type.

I must be missing something here.

```
    interface TodoState {
      todos: Todo[]
    }

//no error
    const arrowFunc: React.FC<TodoState> = ({ todos }) => { }

//error: binding element 'todos' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
    function nonArrow({ todos }): React.FC<TodoState> {}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried actually compiling it to see the error? It looks like an editor or version bug: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const arrowFunc: React.FC<TodoState> = ({ todos }) => {}
//               ^ function type       ^ props        ^ function return value
```

This declares a function, and the type of that function conforms to `React.FC<TodoState>`. Which is to say the functional component accepts props like `TodoState`, plus a `children` property and returns JSX.

```
function nonArrow({ todos }): React.FC<TodoState> {}
//                            ^ function return value
```

But this says something different. `nonArrow` is a function that does not return JSX, it returns a functional component.

The first form types the function as `React.FC<TodoState>`, and the second form types the return value of the function as `React.FC<TodoState>`.

---

There is no syntax to assign an existing function type with the `function` keyword. Typically if you want a functional component to be typed as such, you use the first form.

But that's only helpful if you need `children` as a prop. Otherwise, this simple construct works great for most functional components:

```
function MyFuncComp({ propName }: Props) {
  return <h1>{propName}</h1>
}

// called like this:
<MyFuncComp propName='foo'/>
```

All you need to type most of the time is the props, and then just return some JSX and Typescript+React figure the rest out for you.

---

Or if your component takes children, it's common to do:

```
interface Props {
  propName: string
}

const MyFuncComp: React.FC<Props> = ({ propName, children }) => {
  return <div>
    <h1>{propName}</h1>
    {children}
  </div>
}

// called like this:
<MyFuncComp propName='foo'>
  <p>some children</p>
</MyFuncComp>
```

Comment: Great. What do you mean by `children` property? How does it differ from `props.children`

Comment: `React.FC<Props>` gives you your declared props, _plus_ a `children` prop that typed properly for you. See my update.

Comment: This answer is precisely correct. However if someone really wants to use the type `React.FC<Props>` to describe the type of a `function` declaration, there actually is a way. Using the built in utility types `Parameters<F>` and `ReturnType<F>` it is now possible to deconstruct a function type into its constituents

Comment: @AluanHaddad I suppose you could do that, but I don't think that would pass one of my code reviews :)

Comment: Indeed, I wouldn't suggest it. I find it illustrative in this situation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Type mentioned after the function's parantheses (), indicates the return type,rather than it's own type.

function YourComponentName():React.FC{} indicates return type of this function is a functional component.
Whereas const YourComponentName:React.FC{} indicates the type of this function, i.e a functional component.